# How to avoid function being executed in parallel?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'm using `locationManager(_:didVisit:)` from [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1621529-locationmanager) to get notified when the user arrives at or leaves a location.

However, I find the callback might be called twice sometimes. Because I would save the data I receive into Core Data, I'd like to remove the duplications in those rare cases.

I have no experience with concurrency in Swift. How can I do to avoid the duplicated ClVisit entries.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didVisit visit: CLVisit) {
        if a visit is already in DB {
            return
        }

        // saves the data to DB
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "duplication" and there is no concurrency issue; nothing is being executed "in parallel". These calls are made on the main thread; they cannot overlap. You get an event on arrival and another event on departure, with a different distinct CLVisit object each time. If you are recording this information in CoreData, coping with that is up to you.

Comment: What I mentioned is a corner case that happens rarely. It's also confirmed by others from the community: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101377
I was trying to eliminate the duplicated visits.

Comment: I stand by what I said. Even if the same visit _does_ arrive twice, it is absolutely impossible that this should happen in a "parallel" or "concurrent" manner, because the method is called on the main thread.